# Relation between det(I-A*A) and norm of A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ Complex matrix. Does $\det(I-A^*A)<0$ imply that the operator norm of $A$ i.e $\|A\|$ is strictly less than 1?

Comment: If $n=1$ then $1-|A|^2<0$ for $A\in\mathbb{C}$ rather implies $|A|>1$.

Answer (score 1):

No. If $n=2$ take $A= diag (2, \frac{1}{2}).$

Answer (score 0):

$\det(I-A^\ast A)<0$ means that an odd number of singular values of $A$ is greater than $1$ and the rest are smaller than $1$. Therefore $\|A\|$ is *always greater* than $1$ for every unitarily invariant norm $\|\cdot\|$.

Comment: what is the relation between det(I-A^*A) and the singular values of A?